# FREBitmapData.relase throws FREWrongThreadException

Tags: java, android, adobe, air-native-extension

I'm trying to build an ane who take an empty bitmap

```
bitmapData  = new BitmapData(size.width,size.height,false, 0x00000000);
```

acquire it, edit the bytebuffer in a different thread then release it.

Here's the call function code in the java part

```
public FREObject call(FREContext freContext, FREObject[] args) {
        try {
            FREBitmapData bitmapData = (FREBitmapData)args[0];
            bitmapData.acquire();       
            ByteBuffer bytebuffer = 
            myTaskProcessingQueue.put(new Task(freContext,bitmapData,bytebuffer)); //edit the bitmap data in a specific thread
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
        } catch (FREInvalidObjectException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
        } catch (FREWrongThreadException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And when I'm done with the bytebuffer :

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable () {
                @Override
                public void run () {
                    try {                    
                        Toast.makeText(task.context.getActivity(),"Toast",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
                        task.bitmapData.release();
                    } catch (FREInvalidObjectException e) {
                        Log.e("InitExtractorFunction", "FREInvalidObjectException", e);
                    } catch (FREWrongThreadException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
                    }
                }
            });
```

The toast instruction works fine, but the bitmapData.release() one throws a FREWrongThreadException even though I am on the main thread, and I can't find any documentation about this exception on the adobe website.

Any idea?

**Edit :**

Here's more code for the thread class where i'm editing the data :

```
private class MyTaskWorker extends Thread {


    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                processMyTask(myTaskProcessingQueue.take());


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"InterruptedException", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void processMyTask(Task task) {

            // do work with bytebuffer


            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable () {
                @Override
                public void run () {
                    try {

                        Log.d(TAG, "Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        Toast.makeText(task.context.getActivity(),"Toast",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        task.bitmapData.release();

                        Log.i(TAG,"bitmap released");
                    } catch (FREInvalidObjectException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "FREInvalidObjectException", e);
                    } catch (FREWrongThreadException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG,"FREWrongThreadException", e);
                    }
                }
            });





    }

}
```

**Edit 2 :**

I also tried to do both the acquire and the relase in the same background thread and still no dice. The only way I managed to make it work is when I do both the acquire and the release inside the call function, but I don't want to block the main thread to wait for the bitmap modification...

Answer (score 0):

Just like regular multithreading, whenever you `acquire` a lock, it must be released by the same thread who locked it.

The [documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSb464b1207c184b14-62b8e11f12937b86be4-7ff8.html) for this exception has the following description:

> FRE_WRONG_THREAD The method was called from a thread other than the one on which the runtime has an outstanding call to a native extension function.

Thus when `call()` is called from a background thread, the background thread is the one that locks `bitmapData`, which means the main thread does not own the lock to release it later.

You can always test this by logging the thread name in each location:

```
Log.d(..., "Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

The solution will be to ensure that the `release()` method is invoked from the same place (thread) as `call()` (wherever this may be)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I confirmed that the acquire and the release are both called from the main thread, so I'm unfortunately still stuck.

Comment: You'll need to post a bit more code, showing where each of those methods are used (call and the handler)

Comment: I added more code for the handler part, and the call function is called from the actionscript part.